# Divide String into two labels, bi number of lines in each one

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

[Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLyGw.png)I want to make a text wrap an Image in watchkit, once it is super limited, I found a way to do this by splitting the string int two, and set the first part on the side of the image, and the second under it.

To be clear, I want to create a label, that shows the first two lines of the string. And another one to show the rest. I don't know the string size.

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: Can you show a mockup of what you want?

Comment: I added a mockup showing how it should look. I need two sizes of label, so i need to split my text into two texts, the first is the beginning of the text, in the blue lines, and the second is the rest of the text, in the green lines

Comment: Please tell me if you  found the solution .  me to stuck here :(

Comment: @ChaubeyJi I basically had to select he number of characters that composes two lines, so i search back o front for a space, when found, I print this part of the string (like a character array) and use the rest of it as the second part.